# figures and plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an application in Matlab where I'll be creating lots of plots. Generally, I want each new plot to appear in a a separate figure and also save the handle to the figure, so I do:

```
h = figure('NextPlot','new');
plot(1:13);
```

The above however creates one empty figure and one with the plot(1:13). Why is this?

Comment: Well, `'NextPlot','new'` [means](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html) that the plot should be on a _new_ figure. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LuisMendo For each plot I'm making, I want to make sure it is plotted in a new figure whose handle I can save.

Comment: @LuisMendo I also want to be able to set the title for the figure window. It works when I'm plotting using rectangle, but not when I'm using plot.

Comment: I think you only need to replace `h = figure('NextPlot','new');` by `h = figure;` to create a new figure. Then plot on that figure

Comment: @LuisMendo Weird, but it seems to work. Many thanks! When I plotted using rectangle I had to do h = figure('NextPlot','new'), or at least it worked  as intended when I did,

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

To store the handle you could run something like:

```
for i=1:4
    h(i)=figure(i);
    plot(1:13);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you are good to go with

```
h = figure 
plot(1:13)
```

I tested it in R2010a before posting. The `figure('NextPlot','new')` instructs MATLAB to create a new window (other than being opened) for next plot. That is why you get an empty window + the plot window. By defaut `NextPlot` has the value `add`, and it is for

> Use the current figure to display graphics (the default)